# Empty AJAX Response when debugging with Eclipse

Tags: ajax, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.7.2 for PHP web app development.

When using the debugger (which I have setup to launch the application in Firefox), AJAX calls that are fired quickly contain a blank response when inspected with Firebug.  This is not a cross-domain problem as the AJAX calls are all to the same server.

If I use Firebug to set a breakpoint just before the AJAX call in the JavaScript code, and then resume the execution, then the AJAX response will be loaded correctly.

It seems this problem may be due to Eclipse not being able to handle simultaneous requests.  Is there any way to change Eclipse's settings to allow more requests?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to using Zend Debugger.  Switching to XDebug solved the issue.  Also posted here - [Using Eclipse PDT for debugging Ajax pages with concurrent requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469297/using-eclipse-pdt-for-debugging-ajax-pages-with-concurrent-requests)